# Alias for recursive case insensitive search in current directory

Tags: linux, search, alias, string

How do I set an alias, such as "mysearch", which will search for a string recursively in the directory I'm standing in. It should be as below:

```
mysearch "this table..."
```

=

```
find -type f -exec grep -i -l 'this table...' {} \;
```

Comment: Why do you need `find` at all? `grep` had a recursive (`-r`) option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one:
alias mysearch='find . -type f | xargs grep -i -l $1'

Answer (score 0):

I'd say like this (for bash):

```
function mysearch { grep -ril "$1" .; }
```

The issue with an alias is that it only allows you to append to the command, not insert into the middle. As an alias, this might be more what you want:

```
alias rgrep="grep -ril"
```

Then you could use it like:

```
rgrep "search string" .
```